# Are all rvalue-references lvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Given the code:

```
void foo( int&& i )
{
    int* p = &i;
}
```

`i` is an lvalue. In fact, I can take it's address through the `&` operator.

Is this statement correct?

Comment: A reference is a kind of *type*, not a value. So the question makes no sense. The correct statement is that evaluating an id-expression whose type is rvalue reference produces an lvalue.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, maybe the **statement** does not make sense, but reading https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers I thought that the **question** did

Comment: @PaoloM Universal references (or whatever you want to call them) are different.

Comment: @black Well, universal references aren't rvalue-references. They just have && after the type before it is deduced. Am I wrong?

Comment: @black Forwarding ("universal") references exist in templates and syntax only. Once instantiated, it's either an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression's value category is completely removed from its type.

In your case, the expression `i` is an lvalue, but `std::move(i)` is an rvalue. An expression of rvalue reference type can be an lvalue or rvalue.

Comment: *"An expression's value category is completely removed from its type."* This might be a tad too general. For example, `int& foo();`, one could argue that the *initial type* of `foo()` is `int&`, and that type determines the value category of this function-call-expression. That said, one cannot conclude from the "observed" type of an expression what value category the expression has.